# How to define OccluderPolygon2D in code Godot

Tags: godot

I am using this code

```
    var shape: PoolVector2Array  = [Vector2(0,0), Vector2(0,70), Vector2(70,0), Vector2(70,70)]
set_occluder_polygon(shape)
```

which gives error because of not having same type. I used this because OccluderPolygon2D has PoolVector2Array Polygon

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a `LightOccluder2D` and you want to set its `occluder` (which is a `OccluderPolygon2D`). If it already has one, you should be able to set its points directly. Something like this:

```
$LightOccluder2D.occluder.polygon = shape #PoolVector2Array
```

---

Otherwise, you would have to create a `OccluderPolygon2D`:

```
var new_occluder := OccluderPolygon2D.new()
new_occluder.polygon = shape #PoolVector2Array
$LightOccluder2D.occluder = new_occluder
```